# Where to modify xml for JNDI in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, jdbc, jndi, context.xml

I want to declare global `JNDI` resource for accessing `Mysql` database with `com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlConnectionPoolDataSource` as it described here http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-datasource-examples-howto.html

It is said to edit `Context.xml`.

But it looks like Eclipse overrides `Context.xml`. Should I modify `Context.xml` which is located in `Servers` folder of my workspace?

Can I modify global `server.xml` to have database accessible for all applications? Or it will be overridden by Eclipse's one?

Also I read that `Context.xml` can be put int META-INF. Where I can read about mechanism that processes this location?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is [recommended](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#context.xml_configuration) to put context.xml under META-INF/context.xml in your web application.